# Screen does not switch off when idle

Tags: screen, lock-screen, gnome-screensaver

I'm using 13.04.3 LTS on a desktop machine. Whenever I lock the screen, the screen goes blank for a couple of seconds, but then shows the login screen again. It never actually switches off (the power-saving light never comes on).

gnome-screensaver appears to be running:

```
misha@misha-antec:~$ pidof gnome-screensaver
30126
```

Also, while the screen idle timeout is set to 1 minute, the screen never goes blank or switches off, even when idle for long periods of time.

How can I get my screen to switch off when locked? How can I get the monitor to switch off after it has been idle for some time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was one (or combination of):

- I had VLC running (idling, it wasn't actually playing anything) in the background. VLC was preventing the screensaver from activating)
- I had DPMS timeouts set to zero (check with `xset dpms q`). I set these to non-zero values: `xset dpms 0 0 600` (10 minute timeout)

It all works as expected now.