# Screen OFF vs. Blank screen on inactivity

Tags: screen

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and can't get my screen to turn off on inactivity, the monitor never goes to sleep. It just goes blank, effectively displaying a black screen with the monitor back light still turned on. I never had this issue running versions 12 through 18, but last year I made a fresh install of 21.04 and this is when I first noticed this issue. Now on a brand new install of 22.04, same behavior.  I tried setting the screen off time under Power options in the Settings as well as under Screen options in Privacy.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a4YD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen does not switch off when idle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382873/screen-does-not-switch-off-when-idle)